# TestNG tests under <test> tags are not running parallel in suite parallel="tests"

Tags: parallel-processing, testng

my testng.xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Sanity" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test verbose="2" name="Regression1">
                    <classes>
            <class name="package1.class1">
                <methods>
                    <include name="method1"></include>
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class name="package2.class2">
                <methods>
                    <include name="method2"></include>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test verbose="2" name="Regression2">
                    <classes>
            <class name="package3.class3">
                <methods>
                    <include name="method3"></include>
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class name="package4.class4">
                <methods>
                    <include name="method4"></include>
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class

    </test>
</suite>
```

My requirement here is to run tests in parallel like two browser instances should be launched and in browser instance 1, method1 of Regression1 should run and in browser instance 2, method3 of Regression2 should run, but currently only one thread is being launched with one browser instance only and it executes all the tests one by one from  tags like first Regression1 tests will run sequentially and tests of Regression2. Pls help me to achieve my requirement in TestNG

**UPDATE**

The above testng.xml setup for running test tag tests in parallel is correct, I was having some issue while running testng programmatically which is solved now.

Comment: Your setup is correct.  How are you ascertaining that it is being executed in one thread?  Have you tried printing thread ids?

Comment: Hello Niharika, i am assuming that since i have mentioned thread count as 2, expecting to launch two browser instance parallely by picking the tests from different <test> tags. But only one browser instance is getting launched for the above testng.xml

Comment: Can you do a sysout for Thread.currentThread.getId in the @Test.  Also, it might be an issue with the way you are launching the browser, share that code for someone to be able to help you.